Python KeyError in x.get("key")
This is a weird error I am seeing in a log file in python.
import traceback

mat = [{"a": 1, "b": 2}, {"a": 3, "b": 4}]

def fun(a, b, c):
    if c is None:
        return a + b
    else:
        return a + b + c

try:
    for x in mat:
        x["d"] = fun(x["a"], x["b"], x.get("c"))
except BaseException as e:
    emsg = ''.join(traceback.format_exception(None, e, e.__traceback__))
    print(emsg)

#py> KeyError: "c"

I can't reproduce the error and as far as I understand it should not be possible to get a KeyError for "c" since I am using x.get. Therefore I am quite puzzled by this message. Has anyone an idea, is this a rare error in CPython or I am overlooking something?

There's no issue if I run the code, when you say you can't reproduce do you mean it happened once and never again? Because if so I'd just assume you accidentally used x['c'] earlier and forgot to save before running again

You don't need to explicitly handle the traceback just to get it printed out. A [Mre] (which works fine and returns None): {"a": 1, "b": 2}.get("c").

@Peter that's a valid point but my traceback explicitly shows that the code is x.get("c"), otherwise I wouldn't be puzzled.

@jonrsharpe you are correct, but I know there should not be an error. So my hope is somebody knows there is a corner case when you stand on your left foot and the reference count of xyz is equal to 3 then this can happen. But most likely the error is to exotic to ever identify the reason.

For the sake of completeness you should post the full traceback and information about how you're running the script (eg. visual studio code, IDLE, jupyter). Also try copy that code to a new file and run it again.

Thinking about it more carefully, I guess the answer lies in .pyc file. I updated the .py file to replace x["c"] with x.get("c") before, if now for some reason the overwrite of the .pyc was blocked by another process and the .pyc only references to the line number in the .py file for the traceback (which sounds realistic), this would give the behavior I observed.
Thanks for your help!

If what you're saying is accurate and you can reproduce this you may have found a bug in the Python interpreter - this is interesting behavior I haven't encountered before.
